# segmentation fault while mocking classes with __call() in PHP

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

I'm trying to mock a class that uses magic method __call().

When I run the tests, I got "Segmentation Fault error"

It's a very simple class that forwards calls to methods on its member objects.
I think it's something related to the use of __call(), because the test passes when I remove it.

I'm using PHP 5.3.3 (CentOS 6.5) and PHPunit 4.6

See the code:

```
<?php

use Mockery as m;

class HasRoleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function tearDown()
    {
        m::close();
    }

    function testFoo()
    {
        $foo = m::mock('Foo')->makePartial();
        $this->assertEquals('bar', $foo->bar());
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        if ($name == 'bar')
            return 'bar';

        return 'something else';
    }
}
```

Comment: I read in an online guide to use `\Mockery as m;` with the backslash. It might not fix your problem though, it's just a thing I noticed

Answer (score 1):

Prior to Mockery `1.0.0-alpha`, objects with a `__call` magic method could lead to infinite recursion, which in turn will cause a segfault in PHP.

See, for example, these issues:

- https://github.com/mockery/mockery/issues/564
- https://github.com/mockery/mockery/issues/461
- https://github.com/mockery/mockery/issues/777

This appears to be a bug that has been fixed as of Mockery `1.0.0-alpha`.